# Transpose/reshape rows in columns with given conditions

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
request   user   group
1         1      1
4         1      1
7         1      1
5         1      2
8         1      2
1         2      3
4         2      3
7         2      3
9         2      4
```

I would like to extract the request-sequences and transpose these into columns.

The result should look like this:

```
user   group   request1   request2   request3
1      1       1          4          7
1      2       5          8          NA
2      3       1          4          7
2      4       9          NA         NA
```

I tried to do this with ddply (plyr) but did not come to a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(reshape)

# Make some fake data
dat <- data.frame(user = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2), request = c(1,4,7,5,8,1))
# Add in an ordered id
newdat <- ddply(dat, .(user, group), transform, idx = paste("request", 1:length(request), sep = ""))
# Use cast to get what we want
cast(newdat, user + group ~ idx, value = .(request))
```

There is probably a nicer way to get what I call idx which is essentially what becomes the column title.  It might be possible to do this without creating the newdat data set but this is what I thought of.

Comment: Ok, this does work quite well! Thanks a lot! One Question remains: In my original data I have up to 120 requests per user and group. Cast seems to change the order of the idx-variable like `request1  request2  request3  request4  request5  request6  request10  request11 request7` etc. How to handle that?

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/create-vector-with-fixed-width-fill-with-0/8267036#8267036): Instead of `idx = paste("request", 1:length(request), sep = "")`, `idx = sprintf("request_%03d", 1:length(request))` works great!

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` gets you very close:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    user = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4), 
    group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
    request = c(1,4,7,5,8,1,4,7,9)
)

aggregate(request~group + user, dat, FUN=c)

  group user request
1     1    1 1, 4, 7
2     1    2    5, 8
3     2    3 1, 4, 7
4     2    4       9
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found`