# Format number as fixed width, with leading zeros

Tags: r

The following code

```
a <- seq(1,101,25)
b <- paste("name", 1:length(a), sep = "_")
```

produces this output:

```
"name_1"  "name_26"  "name_51"  "name_76"  "name_101"
```

I'd like to have the same width of all values which means for me to fill the values with zeros like this:

```
"name_001"  "name_026"  "name_051"  "name_076"  "name_101"
```

How do I handle that?

<sub>(This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260808/transpose-reshape-rows-in-coloums-with-given-conditions).)</sub>

Answer (score 258, accepted):

There are several solutions to this.

One of them is to use `sprintf`. This uses `C` style formatting codes embedded in a character string to indicate the format of any other arguments passed to it.  For example, the formatting code `%3d` means format a number as integer of width 3:

```
a <- seq(1,101,25)
sprintf("name_%03d", a)
[1] "name_001" "name_026" "name_051" "name_076" "name_101"
```

Another is `formatC` and `paste`:

```
paste("name", formatC(a, width=3, flag="0"), sep="_")
[1] "name_001" "name_026" "name_051" "name_076" "name_101"
```