# Stuffing numbers when converting to characters

Tags: r, parsing, format

I need to convert a vector of single digit numbers (e.g. `c(1, 2, 3, 45)`) to a character vector where the length of each item is two, and it is stuffed with a zero before the actual number (e.g. `c("01", "02", "03", "45")`.

I could swear that I've done this before in R with some clever function but I can't for the life of me find it or remember what it is... I don't think it's `format()`, but I might be amazed.

**TL;DR:**

What function do I need to convert this:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 45)
```

To this:

```
c("01", "02", "03", "45")
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sprintf` with a padding character:

```
sprintf("%02d",c(1,2,3,45))
```

You could also use `formatC`, it uses basically the same set of formatting conventions (from the C standard library):

```
formatC(c(1,2,3,45),flag=0,width=2)
```

Also, a near-duplicate (sorry, didn't see it before I answered):

[Format number as fixed width, with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 2):

How about a regex

```
sub('(^[0-9]$)','0\\1',c(1,2,3,45))
```