# R: Creating an alphanumeric sequence with fixed length numbers

Tags: r, sequence, alphanumeric

I need to create an alphanumeric sequence as follows. The following code creates the sequence as M_1, M_2, ... etc

```
paste0("M_",seq(1:100))
```

I need all the numbers to appear as 3 digit numbers. i.e. M_001, M_002 etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number as fixed width, with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding leading zeros using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("M_%03d", 1:100)
```