# R - How to change formatting in one column

Tags: r, formatting

is there any option in R to change format of entire column? I have a number containing 13 digits and sometimes is starts with 0 and when I am reading dataframe these zeros are missed. I would like to use something like excel formatting and set up column for 13 digits.

I probably should use something like my.dataframe[,my_column] <-

Regards

Comment: would you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling number of decimal digits in print output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add leading zeroes to a column, you can use the *str_pad* command from the stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
digit <- 123456789
str_pad(digit, width = 13, side = "left", pad = "0")
[1] "0000123456789"
```

Also this might help:
[Format number as fixed width, with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: How can in use this in one column in dataframe? Command like str_pad(mydf[[2]],width = 13, side = "left", pad = "0") show proper result on console but is not changing anything in a data frame.

Comment: it shows you the result because you are asking for the result. If you want to assign the result to something you have to tell R:
mydf$newcolumn <- str_pad(mydf[[2]],width = 13, side = "left", pad = "0")

Comment: Thanks. Now everything is fine :)